# How to modify a user association in Slurm?

Tags: user-accounts, job-scheduler

I want to move a user in Slurm job scheduling system ,from its current group to other group. But there is errors when I try the obvious:

```
sacctmgr modify user where name=example set account=groupb
```

The only way I get is deleting it and creating again with the new account:

```
sacctmgr delete user example account=groupa
sacctmgr add user example account=groupb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found another way using multiple accounts and setting the default one to the last one added:

```
sacctmgr add user example account=groupb
sacctmgr modify user where user=example set defaultaccount=groupb
```

Answer (score 9):

I came over this answer and want to share my insight here:
In Slurm everything is centered around associations. Zhens answer is absolutely right. Just add an new association for that user and delete the old one. Or even leave the old association so the User might decide under which account to run a job (see -U option of srun)

```
sacctmgr remove user where user=example and account=oldgroup
sacctmgr add user name=example defaultaccount=newgroup ...
```